# how to find out the list level and its styles

Tags: list, vba, ms-word

I want to find out the list content in a word document, and its level and style of a list

Nested lists were differentiated by indenting the text

for e.g

```
            1.This simple para

              a.The quick brown  para

              b. This simple para

                i.This simple para

             2.This simple para
              a.This simple para
                i.  This simple para
                ii.This simple para
             3.This simple para
```

Answer (score 1):

Level: `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber`
Style: `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate`